# Pythontex : Input into a pyverbatim environment

Tags: pythontex

With the package Pythontex, I want to input a Python file into  a `pyverbatim` environment :

For example, I tried the code :

```
\begin{pyverbatim}
\input{file_1.py}
\end{pyverbatim}
```

where `file_1.py` is a Python file .

But I obtained as result:

```
\input{file_1.py}
```

and not the `file_1.py`'s content.

How can I do it?

Update. I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyverbatim}
\VerbatimInput{contenus/fichier_1.py}
\end{pyverbatim}

\end{document}
```

and I obtained

```
\VerbatimInput{contenus/fichier_1.py}
```

as result.

Comment: What package provides `pyverbatim`?

Comment: Why not simply `\verbatiminput{file_1.py}`?

Comment: Excuse me: It's with  Pythontex.

Comment: "\begin{pyverbatim}
\VerbatimInput{contenus/fichier_1.py}
\end{pyverbatim}" doesn't work : It produces : "\VerbatimInput{contenus/fichier_1.py}"

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `minted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want `\inputpygments`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

Here's the code in the document
\begin{pyverbatim}
def SI(var, unit):
        return '\\SI{' + str(var) + '}{' + unit + '}'
\end{pyverbatim}
and here we load it from a file
\inputpygments{python}{file_1.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file handler to read code in source and then use it with `pyverbatim` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[temp] 
fh = open("file_1.py")
code = fh.read() 
fh.close()
\end{pycode}

\begin{pysub}[temp] 
  \begin{pyverbatim}
!{code}    
  \end{pyverbatim}
\end{pysub}

\end{document}
```